# There are many missing files in egg packages when run plone 4 buildout

Tags: python, plone, buildout

I need help. I am trying to build plone 4.1 on my Fedora 14 Os. But I got a problem. It seems most of egg packages had many missing files. What I did: `paster create -t plone4_buildout --> python2.6 boottrap.py --> bin/buildout`. I did a workaround: download packages from pypi and replace error packages. Could anyone tell me what happens to me?

My error message:

```
Installing instance.
While:
  Installing instance.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 555, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1227, in _call
return f()
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.1.7-py2.6.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/__init__.py", line 84, in install
make.make_instance(options.get('user', None), location, version)
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.1.7-py2.6.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/make.py", line 23, in make_instance
copyskel(skelsrc, instancehome)
  File "/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.1.7-py2.6.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/make.py", line 65, in copyskel
os.chdir(sourcedir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/thaison/Projects/xxx/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.1.7-py2.6.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/skel213'
```

plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.1.7-py2.6.egg is the first egg package that had missing files. I don't remember exactly but there are many egg packages has the same problem.

Comment: Could you expand your question with an example? Name of package, what files you were expecting but are missing, that kind of thing.

Comment: You're going to need to specify your exact error messages. The procedure you described works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you ran a buildout that finished very badly during an extraction of some egg. Then you re-ran the buildout and the egg seemed to be already present but it was just a half of the real egg. Indeed, if you check the [product](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance/4.1.7) on pypi, the missing dir do exists in the archive and I'm confident that would be the same for any missing file. I would suggest to completely purge the eggs directory and restart the process from the beginning.

I don't think that in this particular case you are facing a problem with SELinux (as you said you are using a Fedora), but just in case, I would also try to temporarly disable it.

Comment: Yes, I think so. My network security may cause this problem. I will determine it later. Now i am using Plone UnifiedInstaller. It works ok. Thanks for your answer!